# Android Studio - Illegal character 8204 error

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-fragments, android-studio

For some reason, after rebuilding my project I get an illegal character error but nothing within my code gets underlined in red. Can someone please tell me what is wrong and how to resolve it?

**Error**

```
illegal character: \8204
```

**WCBankActivity.java**

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;

public class WCBankActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "Station_key";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_wc_bank);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            Intent intent = getIntent();
            String station = intent.getStringExtra(WCBankActivity.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

            FragmentWCBank newFragment = new FragmentWCBank();
            FragmentTransaction transaction = this.getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();‌
            transaction.replace(R.id.detail_container, newFragment);
            transaction.commit();
        }
    }
}
```

[image: 1]

Comment: How can that be done on a Mac?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try changing your encoding, see the image:

[image]

Comment: what should be chosen? I'm currently using `UTF-8`

Answer (score 2):

That's a problem related to BOM (Byte Order Mark) character. Eclipse doesn't allow this character.

```
Just copy paste the same content to a Notepad++ editor,
it shows the "LS" with black background. Have deleted the "LS" content and 
have copy the same content from notepad++ to java file, it works fine.
```

Comment: Please do not post [duplicate answers](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/211726/206345). Instead, consider other actions that could help future users find the answer they need, as described in the linked post.