# Gradle build failed - illegal character '\u0094'

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, build

I've encoutered an error while trying to build the Android project using Gradle. I added the API Key of OpenWeatherAPI to the gradle.properties (copied from their site) and the following code to build.gradle:

```
buildTypes.each {
        it.buildConfigField 'String', 'OPEN_WEATHER_MAP_API_KEY', MyOpenWeatherMapApiKey //for usage in Java code
    }
```

But whenever I try to run my project, I get the error as in title. The **build.config** java is as follows:

```
public final class BuildConfig {
    public static final boolean DEBUG = Boolean.parseBoolean("true");
    public static final String APPLICATION_ID = "com.example.android.sunshine.app";
    public static final String BUILD_TYPE = "debug";
    public static final String FLAVOR = "";
    public static final int VERSION_CODE = 1;
    public static final String VERSION_NAME = "1.0";
    // Fields from build type: debug
    public static final String OPEN_WEATHER_MAP_API_KEY = □myapi□
}
```

I think it might be connected with the encoding in which Gradle is trying to build the project. I've tried the solutions provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30718706/android-studio-illegal-character-8204-error) and unfortunately, they doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: That is the cancel character `"` as seen here http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0094/index.htm in case you are interested.

Comment: Please include the text of the error in your question, not a screen capture of it; screen captures are difficult to parse/read/copy from, and links to images may break.

Comment: Can we see more of your gradle file? `MyOpenWeatherMapApiKey` seems to be giving the issue, since it is registering as `□myapi□`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution. In my gradle.properties file, the APIKey provided by me was in format:

```
MyOpenWeatherMapApiKey=”myapi”
```

Instead of:

```
MyOpenWeatherMapApiKey="myapi"
```

Don't ask me how. Thanks for the tip regarding cancel character, zgc7009.